# Create a Custom Android App UI

Tags: android, android-layout

I am not familiar with creating android apps by any means. However my company is looking to have an app build up. First they would like to have someone design a custom UI for it. However most apps I use at least all generally have the same core UI look/feel which is something we would like to avoid. I have seen apps though that don't even remotely look like the rest. So I am wondering if theres any place to find out what the basic canvas of an android app looks like . Is there any PSD's anywhere for this? Not one hundred percent sure what I am looking for other than concepts at the moment, but we want to know that our concepts are at the least plausible. So if anyone knows any good resources Id be interested to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not PSDs, but you should take a look at the newly launched [Android Design](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html) site, especially the [Building Blocks](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/index.html) section to understand what is available out of the box for you. Pretty much all of the controls you can style pretty extensively if you're willing to put the work into it, but have varying degrees of built-in configurable styling flexibility.

Note that while there's something to be said for ingenuity and being able to stand out from the crowd, there's also the flip side of comfort and usability for the user that comes with a familiar look and feel. If you're looking to come up with your own custom controls, etc. and you're not even familiar with creating Android apps, I hope your company is willing to budget a lot of time for the steep learning curve (the learning curve of Android is not so bad, but adding a lot of custom UI on top of that is not trivial for a first project).

Comment: i think i know why he asked this topic. Because he was from web developer/designer perspective , i guess. :D